# Is a refund for an eBook bought at Google Play possible if it has been downloaded as an ePub?

Tags: google-play-books

When you buy an eBook at the Book Section of Google Play, you can read it in the Google Books app. The Google Play site also has the option to download a copy in ePub format. If you have downloaded a copy as a separate ePub file, can you still get a refund for the book (get the money back and have your access revoked) if you find that you don't want the book anymore? Or does Google not allow a refund if there is a change you have a file copy somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. Just now I went through exactly the process you describe in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is definitely possible.

Recently, I had purchased a book from Google Play Books.

[image]

I then exported it as .epub file and requested for a refund from Google Play stating the reason that I don't need it now. After some time ( say few minutes), I got my refund back. Also, I still have the epub file downloaded in my pc.

[image]